# Facebook iframe shows up, empty, in middle of page

Tags: facebook, wordpress

Just today I noticed on our Wordpress blog that the Facebook iframe is showing up as a blank, bordered box in the middle of my page.

The problem is that when Facebook's JS injects the content, it ends up with a div:

```
<div id="fb-root" class=" fb_reset">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: -2000px;">
        ...iframes here...
    </div>
</div>
```

That "top: -2000px" is not enough to get it off of the visible screen, so it's stuck in the middle of my page.

Is there some way to fix this? I can do something hacky like hide the #fb-root element or shove it way off the screen. That's the one div that's actually in my code -- the rest, including the offending style attribute, are injected by FB's code.

My code just looks like:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
                      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
                      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="(actual URL here)" data-send="false"
        data-layout="button_count" data-width="150" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Comment: I just noticed this as well. Hoping it's a bug they'll fix quickly.

Comment: Yeah, that's sort of what I was wondering...is it a bug, or something I did wrong? I haven't changed anything for quite a while so I didn't think it was something I did.

Comment: I don't think it's something you did, I think it's a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Facebook fixed the bug, because the problem has disappeared.

Comment: Nope, it's still there - however adding `.fb_reset iframe {border: 0px none; width: 0px; height: 0px}` to your css should fix the issue (unless it opens another can of worms).

Comment: It's still fine on our site so I'm not adding any CSS for now.

Comment: it all depends on the height of the page - the initial setting for top value in ".fb_reset iframe" is -10000px, so for example on my "All products" page, where "Like" button appears on the very bottom, and which definitely extends 10000px, a bordered rectangle shows somewhere in the middle. The best solution atm is to add not as I've mentioned above, but "clip: rect(0px 0px 0px 0px)". Initial "width: 0px; height: 0px" doesn't affect iframes, and clipped iframe is still "visible" for the scripts (it's hidden though from human view)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this bug too. But isn't fixed yet.

This bug is not related to wordpress. I see the same behaviour in magento. When the placement of the facebook iframe is at the bottom of the page and the page is longer than 2000px, this occurs. That's also the reason I didn't mention it on any page.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this? I don't want to wait for a solution from Facebook.

Comment: It's definitely fixed on our site. If it's showing up on yours, the way to fix it would be to figure out which element is showing up (inspecting the page) and putting in your own CSS to move the element. I mentioned this in the original question. In my case it was the #fb-root element. Right now it seems like they changed things a bit, so the #fb-root element doesn't contain the offending div. But in any case, you should be able to temporarily fix it by using your own CSS to hide the element, at least until FB changes their HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Last week I noticed the same problem in a vBulletin Forum, but today I checked again and the iframes completely disapeared. The empty div "fb-root" still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem. I had placed  inside an element with relative position and below my blog posts. But when I moved it right after the opening  tag the problem was solved.